# Is it legal to upload PDFs of my papers on a personal website & research-networking websites?

Tags: publications, legal-issues, social-media

I've created a .com personal website where I intend to describe my research, including full-text PDF copies of my published papers. I was going to also make these PDFs available in my account on academic social-networking websites such as ResearchGate and Academia.edu. I've seen many researchers do the same, and indeed these websites will happily accept anything you will upload.

However, I have doubts whether this would actually be legal. Most of my papers are not open-source, and without a subscription, one would just hit the journal's paywall. Is it likely that if I upload these PDFs, I am inviting copyright infringement allegations from the publishers, or any other sort of legal problem? My field, if relevant, is experimental psychology.

Having researched this question on this SE site as well as some of the above-stated ones, I found no conclusive answer. Various proposed alternatives to the uploading of full-text PDFs seem to be to either upload preprints or personal "accepted" (but not journal-formatted) versions, or to state (both on the personal website and on academia.edu etc) that full-text PDFs are available upon individual reasonable request. However, none of these options seem ideal, when you'd simply like whoever is interested in your papers to be able to quickly access them in the obvious places.

Comment: @GoodDeeds it does it indeed! Funny, as I *had* done a search on this website with these keywords, before posting... anyway, thanks!

Comment: You can upload the preprint version anywhere you want before signing the agreement with the publisher. That should be legal, IMO, (I am no lawyer). I could not find this answer right away in the link provided.

Comment: Lots of groups are doing so. Me too. Until the institution doesn't not complain (I post on my page but that is institutional).